# It is possible to enable colour pretty printed Console transport?

Tags: node.js, format, winston

With the following code -

```
import { createLogger, format, transports } from 'winston';

const logger = createLogger({
  format: format.combine(
    format.colorize(),
    format.simple(),
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console(),
  ],
});

logger.info({ message: 'winston test', script: import.meta.url, code: 666 });
```

I see `colorize`d logging -

[image]

With following adjustment -

```
import { createLogger, format, transports } from 'winston';

const logger = createLogger({
  format: format.combine(
    format.colorize(),
    format.prettyPrint(),  \\<=== replaced statement
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console(),
  ],
});

logger.info({ message: 'winston test', script: import.meta.url, code: 666 });
```

I see `prettyPrint`ed JSON logging but the colour has been replaced with `\x1B[32m` and `\x1B[39m`.

[image]

How can I have both `colorize`d and `prettyPrint`ed logging at the same time?